# how to split string of arrays depending only on the comas between arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, split, reduce

I have a string of an array of arrays,and i need to split this string into an array of arrays.

```
array = "[['<1>', 'likes'], ['<2>', 'reads'], ['<3>', \"doesn't have\"]]"
```

this what i've tried so far

```
array.split(",")
```

This is the wanted result:

```
[['<1>','likes'], ['<2>', 'reads'],['<3>', \"doesn't have\"]]
```

Comment: If you change your array elements to use double quotes then you can use `JSON.parse()` on your string to get your array

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: If you make your string a valid JSON string by changing it to use double quotes you can convert it to an array easily with `JSON.parse()`, eg: `const result = JSON.parse('[["<1>", "likes"], ["<2>", "reads"], ["<3>", "doesn\'t have"]]')`

Comment: i'm having this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6

Comment: In both of my comments (and the answer below), we explicitly called out changing your single quotes to double quotes, and we both even provided working examples - please make sure you read through the help that has been provided so far... To make it clearer though, inside of your string you need to change your single quotes `'`, to double quotes `"` so that it can be used with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: this is not my answer, i'm receiving the data like that, so i have to deal with it like that, i can't change it manually

Comment: Do you have control over the backend that is providing you your data (this is something that is good to add to your question)? Seems strange that whatever is providing you with this data would be giving it to you in this format. If needed, I can try & provide a more dynamic solution, but I believe Zach is in the process of updating their answer with one

Comment: @NickParsons Can't think of a non-regex solution (especially as a regex fanboy)

Comment: @ZachJensz hm, yeah, I was thinking to replace single quotes with double quotes `"`, and then parse that, but it gets tricky due to the apostrophe in `doesn't`. I also think you'd need a regular expression to handle that somehow

Comment: I also used regex expression, but i can't handle apostrophe in doesn't

Answer (score 1):

> need to split this string into an array of arrays

As Nick Parsons suggested, change your quotations so they are valid JSON, and use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const array = `[["<1>", "likes"], ["<2>", "reads"], ["<3>", "doesn't have"]]`
console.log(JSON.parse(array))
```

If you are unable to reformat the input string, you can replace the single quotes with double quotes with this crazy regex that took me surprisingly long to craft:

```js
const array = "[['<1>', 'likes'], ['<2>', 'reads'], ['<3>', \"doesn't have\"]]"
const arrayJSON = array.replace(/(?<=[\[\]\, ])'|'(?=[\[\]\, ])/g, `"`)
console.log(arrayJSON)
console.log(JSON.parse(arrayJSON))
```

Comment: NickParsons comment is a more complete explanation, at least add the relevant caveat that the string needs to be valid JSON.

Comment: @pilchard will do

Comment: i'm having an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6

Comment: @Say0 Did you change the single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: okay this is working, but is there any other solution ? because i can't do it manually, i'm receiving data from backend

Comment: @Say0 Oh ok I will update the answer for that then, can you mention this in the question too

Comment: @Say0 That took way longer than I thought sorry, please let me know if the regex works for a wide range of your server input